# How does myfaces.oam.submitForm() work?

Tags: jsf

How can I use

```
myfaces.oam.submitForm()
```

for submitting radio buttons?  I tried

```
myfaces.oam.submitForm('formName', 'formName:radioButtonsName')
```

but it does not seem to work.  Where can I find specifications for this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From google source code (myfaces-js) : https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/myfaces-js-integrationtests/source/browse/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/myfaces/_impl/_util/_OamSubmit.js?r=ad5b5c39ac9e7ecba5f7b20f7cbe3d9ae73a11f3

```
     /**
     * does special form submit remapping
     * remaps the issuing command link into something
     * the decode of the command link on the server can understand
     *
     * @param formName
     * @param linkId
     * @param target
     * @param params
     */
     this.submitForm = function(formName, linkId, target, params) {

          // ...

     }
```